# main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory 2 | #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

Hi i am having some problems with OpenCV i am try to make it open a Image but i keep get that error

this is a sample of my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Load image
    Mat image = imread("redcar.png");

    if (image.empty()) {
        cout << "Failed to load image!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
```

it keeps throwing this error

```
main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

my cmake is this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(projectdetecion VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(projectdetecion main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(projectdetecion ${OpenCV_LIBS})

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

I tried reinstalling my OpenCV and Cmake and reintsalled my MingW compilier any help is appreciated

Comment: did you set your [`configurationProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference) yet?

Comment: @user yes i did set my c_cpp_properties.json but i am still get the same error

Comment: did you run CMake configuration yet? (do you have [vscode-cmake-tools](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools) installed?)

Answer (score 0):

try this

set cmake_prefix_path to directory containing OpenCVConfig.cmake

```
set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=D:\ltc\apis\opencv\build
cmake -S . -B .\bld
```